# Powershell format

Tags: powershell, format

I created my first,(for me complicated) script, and I was wondering if there was an easier way or if it is formatted properly.

My code searches through a folder which contains multiple files that have a datetime at the end of each, ex:noapp.logdatetime.  I want to find the newest file search for a string and if it finds it send an email.  This is what I have so far it seems to work.

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -Filter "noapp.log*" | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 | Select-String  "Pool maximum size exceeded" | Select-Object -First 1
foreach { Send-MailMessage -Subject "Pool Max Exceeded ctdaysis42" -From xx@xx.com  -To xx@xx.com -Body "Pool Max Exceeded ctdaysis42" -SmtpServer mail.xxx.com}
```

Thanks for your comments

Comment: As a best-practice, I'd suggest defining each parameter that you utilize in a script on the cmdlets.  For example, `Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Temp'`.  If you are not using string expansion, you should use string literals (single versus double-quotes)

Comment: I think you've missed a `|` before your ForEach-Object command, but I'm guessing that's not missing from your actual script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying get the latest modified noapp.log file and then check if that log file contains 'Pool maximum size exceeded' and if it does then send mail.

```
$Log = Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -Filter "noapp.log*" | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1

If (Get-Content $Log.fullname | Select-String "Pool maximum size exceeded" ) {     
    Send-MailMessage -Subject "Pool Max Exceeded ctdaysis42" -From xx@xx.com -To xx@xx.com -Body "Pool Max Exceeded ctdaysis42" -SmtpServer mail.xxx.com
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do.  Thank you much!